# Almost sure convergency Uniform distribution

Tags: probability-theory, weak-convergence

We have $f: \left [ 0,1 \right ] \rightarrow \left [ 0,1 \right ]$ continuous.

$\left \{ \xi  \right \}_{n\geq1}$ random variables; $\xi_1\sim Uniform \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

And we consider, $X_n:= f(\xi_n), n\geq 1$

Now, we define $Y_n= \mathbb{I}_{{f(\xi_n)}\geq U_n}$ with $\xi_1, \xi_2, ...U_1,U_2,...$ random variables iid $Uniform \left [ 0,1 \right ]$

And we have to prove that:

$\bar{Y_n} \xrightarrow[]{a.s}  \int_{0}^{1} f(t)dt$

And this is what i do:

By Strong law of large numbers

$\bar{Y_n} \xrightarrow[]{a.s} E(Y_1) = E\left [ \mathbb{I}_{{f(\xi_1)}\geq U_1} \right ] = P(f(\xi_1)\geq U_1$)

But i dont know how to do it after that.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By the law of total probability and since $\xi_1$ and $U$ are uniformly distributed, $P(f(\xi_1)> U_1 ) = \int_0^1 P(f(\xi_1) > U_1|\xi_1 = x) dx  =  \int_0^1 f(x)dx$.

Comment: @EmilianoBarone, I rewrote the solution using the second hint. I'm not sure now that my first hint was very useful...

Comment: I think i get it now, thank you so much!